# .htaccess rewrite altering REQUEST_URI

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have links like so:

```
http://domain/gotothispage
```

That need to be processed like so:

```
http://domain/index.php?req=gotothispage
```

I setup the .htaccess file with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?req=$1
```

I'm finding that the rewrite is working appropriately, but it's generating errors with the script. Instead of the page being processed and displayed correctly, I'm getting the environment variables spit back out on the page, with the REQUEST_URI looking like so:

```
/gotothispage
```

I suspect this is causing issues with the script that is probably expecting a format of:

```
index.php?req=gotothispage
```

Anyone have a suggestion on how to write my rules to sort out this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't guess. Check `index.php` to be sure that REQUEST_URI is the source of the errors. If so, the script is poorly implemented, because what's happening is the proper behavior for REQUEST_URI: it's supposed to hold the original request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"but it's generating errors with the script" => the problem I think of is that **all** your files are being processed, including static files like JavaScript and so on.

Maybe a small filter before is necessary:

```
RewriteEngine On
# if not a static file...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(css|js|htc|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ [NC]
# ...then rewrite to index, keep query string, and stop rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?req=$1 [QSA,L]
```

### And now two hints:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)